# Memcpy a str[ ] to str*

Tags: c, arrays, string, copy

I'm trying to create a xoring function ( I want to XOR 2 strings and return the result).

For that, I need to copy the content a an array (str[ ]) to a string (str* ).

```
char* xor(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    char temp[strlen(str1)];
    char* result = NULL;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=strlen(str1); i++)
    {
        temp[i] = str1[i] ^ str2[i];
    }
    memcpy(result,temp,sizeof(temp)+1);
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting a seg fault for my memcpy.

Am I missing something ? Can you help me ?

Comment: `result` points to `NULL`, not to something where you can write to. You also have some "of by 1" errors.

Comment: As `temp[]` does not include the null character, `i<=strlen(str1)` should be `i<strlen(str1)`. Besides, since `strlen` is constant, you should move it to before the loop and assign it to a variable (you are wasting CPU cycles, nomatter how cheap they are nowadays).

Comment: For the same reason, it should be `memcpy(result,temp,sizeof(temp));` (without the `+1` as there is no `+1`).

Comment: The code further assumes `str1` and `str2` have the same length. Is that correct?

Comment: "I want to XOR 2 strings and return the result", but why ?

Comment: @Amperclock  The function does not make great sense because if one character is present in the both strings then the result string will have an embedded zero character.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking all comments into account, I believe your function should be:

```
char* xor(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int len= strlen(str1)
    char temp[len];

    if (strlen(str2) != len) return 0;
    char *result = malloc(len);

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = str1[i] ^ str2[i];
    }
    memcpy(result,temp,len);
    return result;
}
```

which can be simplified to:

```
char* xor(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int len= strlen(str1)

    if (strlen(str2) != len) return 0;
    char *result = malloc(len);

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        result[i] = str1[i] ^ str2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nicelly summerized ! I'll try and see if it works ! :)

Comment: Note that the result must be considered binary containing null characters and no terminating null, with size as the string(s) length and it must be deallocated with `free`.

Comment: Can I free it after returning it ? (out of the function)

Comment: Yes you can. After all, your function returns a piece of memory from the heap (`malloc`) that you must eventually return to the heap (`free`).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate memory for `result` and you passed `NULL` to `memcpy()`; that is undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *xor(char const *a, char const *b) {
  size_t const size = strlen(a);
  if (size != strlen(b)) {
    return NULL;
  }

  char *result = malloc(size + 1);
  if (!result) {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
  }
  result[size] = '\0';

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the array as `minimum length of 2 strings+1`. Otherwise **you might access array index out of bound** while accessing `str1` and `str2`.

```
for(i=0; i< min( strlen(str1) , strlen(str2) ) ; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = str1[i] ^ str2[i];
    }
temp[i]='\0';
```

You were accessing one element more index than you should. This is where you get the segmentation fault.

Also you didn't allocate anything in `result`. Solution would be something like

```
result = malloc(sizeof(temp));
```

`memcpy()` tries to copy to the memory which is not pointing to any valid determinate portion of memory resulting in undefined behavior.

#### Snippet code

```
size_t min(size_t x, size_t y){
    return x<y?x:y;
}
char* xor(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    char temp[min(strlen(str1),strlen(str2))+1];
    char* result = malloc(sizeof temp);
    if( result == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t i;

    for( i = 0; i <= strlen(str1); i++)
        temp[i] = str1[i] ^ str2[i];
    temp[i] = '\0';
    memcpy(result,temp,sizeof(temp));
    return result;
}
```

To Summarize the problem was -

- Accessing array index out of bound.
- Passing an uninitialized pointer to `memcpy`.
- Also leaving a scope for undefined behavior when the string lengths for the two strings differ.

Now the question is what is the purpose of this process..we may run into nonprintable characters and so on, which are of not much use, from the usual string operation's perspective.

#### One more thing

Your heading of the question was `Memcpy a str[ ] to str*`. Now what you meant was `Memcpy a char[ ] to char*`.

The thing is `char*` holds address of some memory. So when we would copy where will we copy? The memory address pointed by that `char*`. And your case that was simply was an indeterminate uninitialized value. You were copying there - that is UB.

Comment: Additionally length of `str2` should be checked. It might be shorter than `str1`

Comment: @Gerhardh.: Thanks but I have been editing for the example. A bit of wait and you could see what my answer is. Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I get it. I will check the length, malloc the size for the result and will put an '\0' at the end. And I don't mind about the fact that the char gets unprintable ;) !
OH, and the "str" was standing for my variable name (could be anything else).

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate space for `result` using either `malloc` or `calloc`. Currently, `result` is `NULL`. Hence, the segfault.

Moreover, you should not use `sizeof(temp)+1` in your call to `memcpy`. You are invoking [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You are trying to access one byte beyond what you have allocated to `temp`. That's wrong.